# How to get values from array created based on JSON input?

Tags: javascript, json

There is a JSON file containing objects I import to my script. The file looks this way, more or less:

```
{
"names": [
{
    "name": "latacz",
    "displayName": "latacz"
},
{
    "name": "bomkliwer",
    "displayName": "bomkliwer"
},
(...)
```

It gets parsed correctly, values are stored in an object named `sail`, and when I `console.log(sail)` the contents of the object, I get this:

[image]

My question is: how can I get the values, so the `displayName`s and `name`s of the array elements?

Comment: Thank you for not calling it a JSON array :).

Comment: Doing my best ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var names = sail.names;

names.forEach(function(item){
    var name = item.name;
    // Console.log("name: ", name);
    var displayName = item.displayName;
    // Console.log("displayName: ", displayName);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `sail.names[0].name` and `sail.names[0].displayName`?

However, I don't understand what you need the name `sail` for, if the array already has its name `names`. I would decide for one.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getData(sail){
   sail.forEach(function(item){
      console.log('name:', item.name);
      console.log('displayName:', item.displayName);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Object has an array element named "names". You should navigate for this array.

```js
var a = "Your Object";
for(var i of a.names){
  console.log(i);
  console.log(i.name);
  console.log(i.display);
}
```